# Is there an option in R's builtin function plot to manually set one limit?

Tags: r, plot

Is there an option in R's builtin function plot to manually set one limit?

For example, 
I want to just set the minimum y value as 0 in this plot:

```
evalues = c(2.88, 1.44, 1.16, 1.02, 0.71, 0.65, 0.56, 0.35, 0.23)
plot(evalues, type="b", main="Scree plot")
```

Comment: How about `ylim = c(0, max(evalues))` ?

Comment: Well, I am looking to set the minimum, without changing the maximum.

Comment: That doesn't change the maximum since the default ylim is `c(min(y), max(y))`

Comment: Thanks, but that is what I am trying to avoid.